# Amazon Quicksight Dashboard Functionality

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I just wanted to see if there was a way to give the user access to adjust the aggregate by hour/day/week/month/year. I know it is possible in the Analysis but I would like to allow the end user that ability so I can just have one Sales Visual that the user can aggregate  rather than having a sales by Day/ Sales by Month/ Sales by Year.

Let me know if this is possible.

Thank you,
Casey

Answer (score 1):

Choose a visual, in the fields well you can add either an hierarchy or add field like the screenshot.

[image]

Then you can drill down on dashboards too.

[image]